# Access to the path is denied in C# Visual Express 2010

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, filestream, aforge

I'm using Visual C# Express 10. I'm trying to create, open and write to a .avi file from another .avi file. I'm using Aforge dlls for y project. The following code was programmed in a button click.

```
OpenFileDialog toy = new OpenFileDialog();

            toy.Filter = "AVI files (*.avi)|*.avi|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            toy.Title = "Open an AVI file";
            toy.ShowDialog();
            string wish = toy.FileName;
            VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
            VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
            string fileName = @"C:\test.avi";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

I'm getting error in above line

```
            // open video file
            reader.Open(wish);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
                int w = videoFrame.Width;
                int h = videoFrame.Height;
                writer.Open(@"C:\test.avi",w, h);
                videoFrame.Save(i + ".bmp");
                // dispose the frame when it is no longer required
                //videoFrame.Dispose();
            }
            reader.Close();
```

The error I receive is "Access to the path 'C:\test.avi' is denied".
I have tried a few solutions in StackOverflow which included changing permissions of C drive and using environmental folders. Please advise me on this.

EDIT:
Sorry for the delay. I cant write the log file as well. I'm trying to upload a pic

EDIT 2:
This is the exception. I got it from textbox and just typed it out. I replaced my name with xxxx though.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\test.avi' is denied.
at System.IO._Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 buffersize, FileOptions)
options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy,
Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean
bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
at VideoFramesTest.Form1.OpenAndSave() in
C:\Users\XXXX\documents\visual studio
2010\projects\VideoFramestest\VideoFramestest\Form1.cs:line42
```

Comment: Well it seems that Aforge has nothing to do with this - your entire question could be written without any dialogs or anything similar, just with the creation of the `FileStream`. After all, you don't get as far as writing anything to the file. What environment is this - is it a local client app, or a web app, or what? Are you able to write to the root directory of the drive from the command line or in Explorer?

Comment: Its a windows form. Its the first step of a large application. I need to include several features but I'm stuck in the beginning. As for your other question, I can write to the root folder through command line. I dont exactly know how to write using explorer though.

Comment: this could be a variety of different things, wrap your `writer.open` in a try catch and post the exception. File could be open, you may need admin access. we dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem by doing this.
I changed the save file path to c:users....desktop
Apparently, we cant write directly in C:.
It also works if a new folder is created in C: (like C:\test\test.avi)
Thats the solution. 
And also, I tried System.IO.File.Create(fileName). Works as well. 
Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My guess given your experience with c# would be you have `test.avi` open

a better thing to do would be to wrap your for loop in a `try/catch` like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   try
   {

       Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
       int w = videoFrame.Width;
       int h = videoFrame.Height;
       writer.Open(@"C:\test.avi",w, h);
       videoFrame.Save(i + ".bmp");
       // dispose the frame when it is no longer required
       //videoFrame.Dispose();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   //show my exception
   }
}
```

I would also suggest you also look at [Using Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to handle resources

Comment: There is no test.avi for it to be open. Also, the error is coming at declaring streamwriter.

Comment: @detectiveFishLegs, Wait... You're trying to open a `FileStream` for a file that doesn't exist? There's your problem right there... How do you expect that to happen? What are you wanting to get back? Make sure your file exists before newing up a `FileStream` that's just common sense

Comment: `FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);` this line should probably be `FileStream fs = new FileStream(wish, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);` in your code. Take out `test.avi`

Comment: FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate) Does this not create a new file if it does not exist?

Comment: That makes no sense. replacing 'fileName' with 'wish' makes the program to write to the opened file

Comment: @detectiveFishLegs I think I have gathered what you are trying to do. load in a file and create a new file from it. You must first load in the old file to a FileStream as I did with my code and write it to another file. new FileStream does not create a new file if it does not exist.